how to handle classification tasks with non-mutually exclusive labels?
I’m working on a classification problem where instances can belong to multiple classes simultaneously. For example:

A movie can be tagged with multiple genres, such as "Action," "Comedy," and "Drama."
A patient might be diagnosed with multiple diseases based on their symptoms.

This setup differs from standard classification tasks, where each instance belongs to exactly one class.
Challenges:

Standard classifiers (e.g., logistic regression, SVMs) are designed for mutually exclusive labels, as far asI know. How do I adapt them for multi-label data?
Some labels are correlated (e.g., "Action" and "Thriller"), and ignoring these dependencies might reduce accuracy.

Potential Approaches:
I’ve read about multi-label classification techniques, such as:

Binary Relevance: Treat each label as a separate binary classification task by training an independent classifier for each label. While simple and scalable, this method assumes labels are independent, which may not capture underlying correlations effectively.

Classifier Chains: Predict labels sequentially by chaining classifiers, where each classifier’s output is included as an additional feature for subsequent predictions. This approach captures label dependencies but may be computationally intensive, particularly for a large number of labels.

Mixed Effects Least Squares Support Vector Machine: Incorporates random effects to account for hierarchical dependencies and variations within grouped data, allowing for better handling of label correlations and structured data relationships.

Deep Learning Models: Use shared neural network architectures to learn representations for all labels simultaneously, enabling the capture of both independent and dependent relationships between labels. Custom loss functions, such as binary cross-entropy, are optimised for multi-label settings.


Questions:

Which approach is most suitable for multi-label classification tasks, and how do I decide based on my data?
What are the practical steps to implement these approaches in Python using libraries like scikit-learn or TensorFlow?

